# How do I install a Python module?

Tags: python, installation

Be forewarned, issues related to installing Python make me nervous.  I spent an entire morning panicking what would happen when I would install Python 3.

Now on to the task.  My computer is an Apple.  I would like to add a python module that I have downloaded from the internet.  How do I install the package?

I tried 'python setup.py install' but received an error:

```
    error: could not create '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/bs4': Permission denied
```

Please help.  Thank you.

Comment: use `sudo python setup.py install` to run the command with elevated privileges

Comment: use python3 if you would like to install the package for python3. On the side note, if you would like to experiment with Python with no regrets, start using virtualenv.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use elevated privileges to do this by using [sudo](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/sudo.8.html)

```
sudo python setup.py install
```

Comment: That wasn't so scary, but I was surprised when it asked for my password.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively to installing with elevated privileges, you could also use virtualenv to create a self-contained environment in user space, then install things to that with regular user privileges.  This also has other benefits over installing to the system Python, such as keeping your dependencies clear, and not accidentally breaking your system install with some funky package.